# Navigation bar and bookmarks problems, aligning table content vertically

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make a custom website based on Wikipedia article, and ran into few problems.

1. After jumping to particular section from navigation bar, navigation bar obscures top part of content. How to make it jump to a higher position?
2. While almost all jumps from navigation bar work (beside 1. problem), the #summary one goes way too high, in the same place as #intro and #infobox.
3. Is it possible to switch header and navigation positions in a way that while on the top of the page navigation bar will be placed under header, but after scrolling down it will stick to top page border?
4. How do I align vertically to the top content of infobox table cells is such a way that will allow to make the website responsive (no fixed paddings)?

If possible, I'd like to avoid flexbox solutions. I'll be grateful for any advice :)

```css
* {
  /*box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;*/
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

nav li:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav li {
  float: left;
  width: 8.33%;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

nav a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

main {
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

h1, h2, h4, figure {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
}

#intro {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}

#infobox {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The Myth of Sisyphus</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#infobox">Infobox</a></li>
    <li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
    <li><a href="#summary">Summary</a></li>
    <li><a href="#chapter_1">Chapter 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#chapter_2">Chapter 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#chapter_3">Chapter 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#chapter_4">Chapter 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#appendix">Appendix</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sources">Sources</a></li>
    <li><a href="#see_also">See also</a></li>
    <li><a href="#external_links">External links</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main>
  <header id="home">
    <h1>The Myth of Sisyphus</h1>
  </header>

  <aside id="infobox">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/75/Le_Mythe_de_Sisyphe.jpg" alt="Book cover">

      <figcaption>Cover of the first edition</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Author</th>
        <td><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Camus">
          Albert Camus</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Original title</th>
        <td><cite lang="fr">Le Mythe de Sisyphe</cite></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Translator</th>
        <td>Justin O'Brien</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <td>France</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Language</th>
        <td>French</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <td><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existentialism">
          Existentialism</a>,
          <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absurdism">Absurdism</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Published</th>
        <td>1942 (<a lang="fr" href=
          "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89ditions_Gallimard">Éditions
          Gallimard</a>, in French)<br> 1955
          (<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamish_Hamilton">Hamish
          Hamilton</a>, in English)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Media type</th>
        <td>Print</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><a href=
          "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number">
          ISBN</a></th>
        <td><a href=
          "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/0-679-73373-6">
          0-679-73373-6</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </aside>

  <section id="intro">
    <h2>Introduction</h2>

    <p><b><cite>The Myth of Sisyphus</cite></b>
      (<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_language">French</a>:
      <cite lang="fr">Le Mythe de Sisyphe</cite>) is a 1942 philosophical essay by
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Camus">Albert Camus</a>.
      The English translation by Justin O'Brien was first published in 1955.</p>

    <p>In the essay, Camus introduces his philosophy of the
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absurdism">absurd</a>: man's futile
      search for meaning, unity, and clarity in the face of an unintelligible
      world devoid of God and eternal truths or values. Does the realization
      of the absurd require suicide? Camus answers: "No. It requires revolt."
      He then outlines several approaches to the absurd life. The final chapter
      compares the absurdity of man's life with the situation of
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus">Sisyphus</a>, a figure of
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_mythology">
      Greek mythology</a> who was condemned to repeat forever the same
      meaningless task of pushing a boulder up a mountain, only to see it roll
      down again. The essay concludes, "The struggle itself [...] is enough to
      fill a man's heart. One must imagine Sisyphus happy."</p>

    <p>The work can be seen in relation to other absurdist works by Camus:
      the novel <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stranger_(novel)">
      <cite>The Stranger</cite></a> (1942), the plays
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Misunderstanding">
      <cite>The Misunderstanding</cite></a> (1942) and
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caligula_(play)">
      <cite>Caligula</cite></a> (1944), and especially the essay
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rebel_(book)">
      <cite>The Rebel</cite></a> (1951).</p>
  </section>

  <section id="summary">
    <h2>Summary</h2>

    <p>The essay is dedicated to
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_Pia">Pascal Pia</a>
      and is organized in four chapters and one appendix.</p>

    <section id="chapter_1">
      <h3>Chapter 1: An Absurd Reasoning</h3>

      <p>Camus undertakes the task of answering what he considers to be the only
        question of <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy">
        philosophy</a> that matters: Does the realization of the meaninglessness
        and absurdity of life necessarily require suicide?</p>

      <p>He begins by describing the absurd condition: Much of our life is built
        on the hope for tomorrow, yet tomorrow brings us closer to death,
        the ultimate enemy; people live as if they didn't know about the
        certainty of death. Once stripped of its common romanticism, the world
        is a foreign, strange and inhuman place; true knowledge is impossible,
        and rationality and science cannot reveal the world—such explanations
        ultimately end in meaningless abstractions and metaphors. "From the
        moment absurdity is recognized, it becomes a passion, the most harrowing
        of all."</p>

      <p>It is not the world that is absurd, nor human thought: the absurd
        arises when the human need to understand meets the unreasonableness
        of the world, when "my appetite for the absolute and for unity" meets
        "the impossibility of reducing this world to a rational and reasonable
        principle."</p>

      <p>He then characterizes a number of philosophies that describe and
        attempt to deal with this feeling of the absurd, by
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Heidegger">Heidegger</a>,
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Jaspers">Jaspers</a>,
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lev_Shestov">Shestov</a>,
        <a href=
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8ren_Kierkegaard">Kierkegaard</a>,
        and <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_Husserl">Husserl</a>.
        All of these, he claims, commit "philosophical suicide" by reaching
        conclusions that contradict the original absurd position, either
        by abandoning reason and turning to God, as in the case of Kierkegaard
        and Shestov, or by elevating reason and ultimately arriving at
        ubiquitous <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_Forms">
        Platonic forms</a> and an abstract god, as in the case of Husserl.</p>

      <p>For Camus, who set out to take the absurd seriously and follow it to
        its final conclusions, these "leaps" cannot convince. Taking the absurd
        seriously means acknowledging the contradiction between the desire of
        human reason and the unreasonable world. Suicide, then, also must be
        rejected: without man, the absurd cannot exist. The contradiction must
        be lived; reason and its limits must be acknowledged, without false
        hope. However, the absurd can never be accepted: it requires constant
        confrontation, constant revolt.</p>

      <p>While the question of human
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_will">freedom in the
        metaphysical sense</a> loses interest to the absurd man, he gains
        freedom in a very concrete sense: no longer bound by hope for a better
        future or eternity, without a need to pursue life's purpose or to create
        meaning, "he enjoys a freedom with regard to common rules".</p>

      <p>To embrace the absurd implies embracing all that the unreasonable world
        has to offer. Without a meaning in life, there is no scale of values.
        "What counts is not the best living but the most living."</p>

      <p>Thus, Camus arrives at three consequences from fully acknowledging
        the absurd: revolt, freedom, and passion.</p>
    </section>

    <section id="chapter_2">
      <h3>Chapter 2: The Absurd Man</h3>

      <p>Camus then goes on to present examples of the absurd life. He begins
        with <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Juan">Don Juan</a>,
        the serial seducer who lives the passionate life to the fullest.
        "There is no noble love but that which recognizes itself to be both
        short-lived and exceptional."</p>

      <p>The next example is the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor">
        actor</a>, who depicts ephemeral lives for ephemeral fame.
        "He demonstrates to what degree appearing creates being." "In those
        three hours he travels the whole course of the dead-end path that
        the man in the audience takes a lifetime to cover."</p>

      <p>Camus's third example of the absurd man is the conqueror, the warrior
        who forgoes all promises of eternity to affect and engage fully
        in human history. He chooses action over contemplation,
        aware of the fact that nothing can last and no victory is final.</p>
    </section>

    <section id="chapter_3">
      <h3>Chapter 3: Absurd Creation</h3>

      <p>Here Camus explores the absurd creator or artist. Since explanation
        is impossible, absurd art is restricted to a description of the myriad
        experiences in the world. "If the world were clear, art would
        not exist." Absurd creation, of course, also must refrain from judging
        and from alluding to even the slightest shadow of hope.</p>

      <p>He then analyzes the work of
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fyodor_Dostoyevsky">
        <cite>Dostoyevsky</cite></a> in this light, especially
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Writer%27s_Diary">
        <cite>The Diary of a Writer</cite></a>,
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demons_(Dostoyevsky_novel)">
        <cite>The Possessed</cite></a> and
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brothers_Karamazov">
        <cite>The Brothers Karamazov</cite></a>. All these works start from
        the absurd position, and the first two explore the theme
        of philosophical suicide. However, both The Diary and his last novel,
        The Brothers Karamazov, ultimately find a path to hope and faith
        and thus fail as truly absurd creations.</p>
    </section>

    <section id="chapter_4">
      <h3>Chapter 4: The Myth of Sisyphus</h3>

      <p>In the last chapter, Camus outlines the legend of Sisyphus who defied
        the gods and put Death in chains so that no human needed to die. When
        Death was eventually liberated and it came time for Sisyphus himself
        to die, he concocted a deceit which let him escape from the underworld.
        Finally captured, the gods decided on his punishment for all eternity.
        He would have to push a rock up a mountain; upon reaching the top,
        the rock would roll down again, leaving Sisyphus to start over. Camus
        sees Sisyphus as the absurd hero who lives life to the fullest, hates
        death, and is condemned to a meaningless task.</p>

      <p>Camus is interested in Sisyphus' thoughts when marching down
        the mountain, to start anew. After the stone falls back down
        the mountain Camus states that "It is during that return, that pause,
        that Sisyphus interests me. A face that toils so close to stones
        is already stone itself! I see that man going back down with a heavy yet
        measured step toward the torment of which he will never know the end."
        This is the truly tragic moment, when the hero becomes conscious of his
        wretched condition. He does not have hope, but "there is no fate that
        cannot be surmounted by scorn." Acknowledging the truth will conquer it;
        Sisyphus, just like the absurd man, keeps pushing. Camus claims that
        when Sisyphus acknowledges the futility of his task and the certainty
        of his fate, he is freed to realize the absurdity of his situation
        and to reach a state of contented acceptance. With a nod to
        the similarly cursed Greek hero
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oedipus">Oedipus</a>, Camus
        concludes that "all is well," indeed, that "one must imagine Sisyphus
        happy."</p>
    </section>

    <section id="appendix">
      <h3>Appendix</h3>

      <p>The essay contains an appendix titled "Hope and the Absurd in the work
        of <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Kafka">Franz Kafka</a>".
        While Camus acknowledges that Kafka's work represents an exquisite
        description of the absurd condition, he maintains that Kafka fails as
        an absurd writer because his work retains a glimmer of hope.</p>
    </section>
  </section>

  <section id="sources">
    <h2>Sources</h2>

    <ul>
      <li><cite>The Plague, The Fall, Exile and the Kingdom, and Selected
        Essays</cite>, Albert Camus,
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_A._Knopf">
        Alfred A. Knopf</a> 2004, <a href=
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/1400042550">
        ISBN 1-4000-4255-0</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <section id="see_also">
    <h2>See also</h2>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absurdism">Absurdism</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_return">
        Eternal return</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theatre_of_the_Absurd">
        Theatre of the Absurd</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sickness_Unto_Death">
        The Sickness Unto Death</a> by <a lang="da" href=
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8ren_Kierkegaard">
        Søren Kierkegaard</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <section id="external_links">
    <h2>External links</h2>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://dbanach.com/sisyphus.htm">Chapter 4 of the essay
        The Myth of Sisyphus</a>, by Albert Camus</li>
      <li><a href="http://www.sparknotes.com/philosophy/sisyphus/summary.html">
        SparkNotes on The Myth of Sisyphus</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20071012140207/http://www.geocities.com/a_and_e_uk/Sisyphus.htm">
        Suicide and Atheism: Camus and The Myth of Sisyphus</a> at the
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_Machine">Wayback
        Machine</a> (archived October 12, 2007) by Richard Barnett</li>
      <li><a href="https://www.viu.ca/events/albert-camus-absurd-hero">
        The Absurd Hero</a> by Bob Lane</li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <h4>Created by Name Surname<br>Source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Myth_of_Sisyphus">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Myth_of_Sisyphus</a></h4>
  </footer>

</main>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: nav li {float: left;} is making it run side to side to each other. Just comment that declaration and the list will run vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Here's 1, 2 and 4. If you want to do this without `js` then all you have to do is add more space to account for the sticky navigation on top.

3. is not possible without `js`.

```css
* {
  /*box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;*/
}

#main > section, #summary{
  padding-top: 80px;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav ul {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

nav li:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

nav li {
  float: left;
  width: 8.33%;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1.5rem 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

nav a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

main {
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  color: white;
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

h1, h2, h4, figure {
  text-align: center;
}

table {
  margin: auto;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
}

#intro {
  width: 70%;
}

#infobox {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 900px) {
  #infobox {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  #intro {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>The Myth of Sisyphus</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#infobox">Infobox</a></li>
    <li><a href="#intro">Intro</a></li>
    <li><a href="#summary">Summary</a></li>
    <li><a href="#chapter_1">Chapter 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#chapter_2">Chapter 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#chapter_3">Chapter 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#chapter_4">Chapter 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#appendix">Appendix</a></li>
    <li><a href="#sources">Sources</a></li>
    <li><a href="#see_also">See also</a></li>
    <li><a href="#external_links">External links</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<main>
  <header id="home">
    <h1>The Myth of Sisyphus</h1>
  </header>

  <aside id="infobox">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/75/Le_Mythe_de_Sisyphe.jpg" alt="Book cover">

      <figcaption>Cover of the first edition</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Author</th>
        <td><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Camus">
          Albert Camus</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Original title</th>
        <td><cite lang="fr">Le Mythe de Sisyphe</cite></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Translator</th>
        <td>Justin O'Brien</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Country</th>
        <td>France</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Language</th>
        <td>French</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <td><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existentialism">
          Existentialism</a>,
          <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absurdism">Absurdism</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Published</th>
        <td>1942 (<a lang="fr" href=
          "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89ditions_Gallimard">Éditions
          Gallimard</a>, in French)<br> 1955
          (<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamish_Hamilton">Hamish
          Hamilton</a>, in English)</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Media type</th>
        <td>Print</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th><a href=
          "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number">
          ISBN</a></th>
        <td><a href=
          "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/0-679-73373-6">
          0-679-73373-6</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </aside>

  <section id="intro">
    <h2>Introduction</h2>

    <p><b><cite>The Myth of Sisyphus</cite></b>
      (<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_language">French</a>:
      <cite lang="fr">Le Mythe de Sisyphe</cite>) is a 1942 philosophical essay by
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Camus">Albert Camus</a>.
      The English translation by Justin O'Brien was first published in 1955.</p>

    <p>In the essay, Camus introduces his philosophy of the
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absurdism">absurd</a>: man's futile
      search for meaning, unity, and clarity in the face of an unintelligible
      world devoid of God and eternal truths or values. Does the realization
      of the absurd require suicide? Camus answers: "No. It requires revolt."
      He then outlines several approaches to the absurd life. The final chapter
      compares the absurdity of man's life with the situation of
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sisyphus">Sisyphus</a>, a figure of
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_mythology">
      Greek mythology</a> who was condemned to repeat forever the same
      meaningless task of pushing a boulder up a mountain, only to see it roll
      down again. The essay concludes, "The struggle itself [...] is enough to
      fill a man's heart. One must imagine Sisyphus happy."</p>

    <p>The work can be seen in relation to other absurdist works by Camus:
      the novel <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stranger_(novel)">
      <cite>The Stranger</cite></a> (1942), the plays
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Misunderstanding">
      <cite>The Misunderstanding</cite></a> (1942) and
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caligula_(play)">
      <cite>Caligula</cite></a> (1944), and especially the essay
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rebel_(book)">
      <cite>The Rebel</cite></a> (1951).</p>
  </section>

  <section id="main">
    <h2 id="summary">Summary</h2>

    <p>The essay is dedicated to
      <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_Pia">Pascal Pia</a>
      and is organized in four chapters and one appendix.</p>

    <section id="chapter_1">
      <h3>Chapter 1: An Absurd Reasoning</h3>

      <p>Camus undertakes the task of answering what he considers to be the only
        question of <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philosophy">
        philosophy</a> that matters: Does the realization of the meaninglessness
        and absurdity of life necessarily require suicide?</p>

      <p>He begins by describing the absurd condition: Much of our life is built
        on the hope for tomorrow, yet tomorrow brings us closer to death,
        the ultimate enemy; people live as if they didn't know about the
        certainty of death. Once stripped of its common romanticism, the world
        is a foreign, strange and inhuman place; true knowledge is impossible,
        and rationality and science cannot reveal the world—such explanations
        ultimately end in meaningless abstractions and metaphors. "From the
        moment absurdity is recognized, it becomes a passion, the most harrowing
        of all."</p>

      <p>It is not the world that is absurd, nor human thought: the absurd
        arises when the human need to understand meets the unreasonableness
        of the world, when "my appetite for the absolute and for unity" meets
        "the impossibility of reducing this world to a rational and reasonable
        principle."</p>

      <p>He then characterizes a number of philosophies that describe and
        attempt to deal with this feeling of the absurd, by
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martin_Heidegger">Heidegger</a>,
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Jaspers">Jaspers</a>,
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lev_Shestov">Shestov</a>,
        <a href=
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8ren_Kierkegaard">Kierkegaard</a>,
        and <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmund_Husserl">Husserl</a>.
        All of these, he claims, commit "philosophical suicide" by reaching
        conclusions that contradict the original absurd position, either
        by abandoning reason and turning to God, as in the case of Kierkegaard
        and Shestov, or by elevating reason and ultimately arriving at
        ubiquitous <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_Forms">
        Platonic forms</a> and an abstract god, as in the case of Husserl.</p>

      <p>For Camus, who set out to take the absurd seriously and follow it to
        its final conclusions, these "leaps" cannot convince. Taking the absurd
        seriously means acknowledging the contradiction between the desire of
        human reason and the unreasonable world. Suicide, then, also must be
        rejected: without man, the absurd cannot exist. The contradiction must
        be lived; reason and its limits must be acknowledged, without false
        hope. However, the absurd can never be accepted: it requires constant
        confrontation, constant revolt.</p>

      <p>While the question of human
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_will">freedom in the
        metaphysical sense</a> loses interest to the absurd man, he gains
        freedom in a very concrete sense: no longer bound by hope for a better
        future or eternity, without a need to pursue life's purpose or to create
        meaning, "he enjoys a freedom with regard to common rules".</p>

      <p>To embrace the absurd implies embracing all that the unreasonable world
        has to offer. Without a meaning in life, there is no scale of values.
        "What counts is not the best living but the most living."</p>

      <p>Thus, Camus arrives at three consequences from fully acknowledging
        the absurd: revolt, freedom, and passion.</p>
    </section>

    <section id="chapter_2">
      <h3>Chapter 2: The Absurd Man</h3>

      <p>Camus then goes on to present examples of the absurd life. He begins
        with <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Juan">Don Juan</a>,
        the serial seducer who lives the passionate life to the fullest.
        "There is no noble love but that which recognizes itself to be both
        short-lived and exceptional."</p>

      <p>The next example is the <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor">
        actor</a>, who depicts ephemeral lives for ephemeral fame.
        "He demonstrates to what degree appearing creates being." "In those
        three hours he travels the whole course of the dead-end path that
        the man in the audience takes a lifetime to cover."</p>

      <p>Camus's third example of the absurd man is the conqueror, the warrior
        who forgoes all promises of eternity to affect and engage fully
        in human history. He chooses action over contemplation,
        aware of the fact that nothing can last and no victory is final.</p>
    </section>

    <section id="chapter_3">
      <h3>Chapter 3: Absurd Creation</h3>

      <p>Here Camus explores the absurd creator or artist. Since explanation
        is impossible, absurd art is restricted to a description of the myriad
        experiences in the world. "If the world were clear, art would
        not exist." Absurd creation, of course, also must refrain from judging
        and from alluding to even the slightest shadow of hope.</p>

      <p>He then analyzes the work of
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fyodor_Dostoyevsky">
        <cite>Dostoyevsky</cite></a> in this light, especially
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Writer%27s_Diary">
        <cite>The Diary of a Writer</cite></a>,
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demons_(Dostoyevsky_novel)">
        <cite>The Possessed</cite></a> and
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Brothers_Karamazov">
        <cite>The Brothers Karamazov</cite></a>. All these works start from
        the absurd position, and the first two explore the theme
        of philosophical suicide. However, both The Diary and his last novel,
        The Brothers Karamazov, ultimately find a path to hope and faith
        and thus fail as truly absurd creations.</p>
    </section>

    <section id="chapter_4">
      <h3>Chapter 4: The Myth of Sisyphus</h3>

      <p>In the last chapter, Camus outlines the legend of Sisyphus who defied
        the gods and put Death in chains so that no human needed to die. When
        Death was eventually liberated and it came time for Sisyphus himself
        to die, he concocted a deceit which let him escape from the underworld.
        Finally captured, the gods decided on his punishment for all eternity.
        He would have to push a rock up a mountain; upon reaching the top,
        the rock would roll down again, leaving Sisyphus to start over. Camus
        sees Sisyphus as the absurd hero who lives life to the fullest, hates
        death, and is condemned to a meaningless task.</p>

      <p>Camus is interested in Sisyphus' thoughts when marching down
        the mountain, to start anew. After the stone falls back down
        the mountain Camus states that "It is during that return, that pause,
        that Sisyphus interests me. A face that toils so close to stones
        is already stone itself! I see that man going back down with a heavy yet
        measured step toward the torment of which he will never know the end."
        This is the truly tragic moment, when the hero becomes conscious of his
        wretched condition. He does not have hope, but "there is no fate that
        cannot be surmounted by scorn." Acknowledging the truth will conquer it;
        Sisyphus, just like the absurd man, keeps pushing. Camus claims that
        when Sisyphus acknowledges the futility of his task and the certainty
        of his fate, he is freed to realize the absurdity of his situation
        and to reach a state of contented acceptance. With a nod to
        the similarly cursed Greek hero
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oedipus">Oedipus</a>, Camus
        concludes that "all is well," indeed, that "one must imagine Sisyphus
        happy."</p>
    </section>

    <section id="appendix">
      <h3>Appendix</h3>

      <p>The essay contains an appendix titled "Hope and the Absurd in the work
        of <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Franz_Kafka">Franz Kafka</a>".
        While Camus acknowledges that Kafka's work represents an exquisite
        description of the absurd condition, he maintains that Kafka fails as
        an absurd writer because his work retains a glimmer of hope.</p>
    </section>
  </section>

  <section id="sources">
    <h2>Sources</h2>

    <ul>
      <li><cite>The Plague, The Fall, Exile and the Kingdom, and Selected
        Essays</cite>, Albert Camus,
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_A._Knopf">
        Alfred A. Knopf</a> 2004, <a href=
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:BookSources/1400042550">
        ISBN 1-4000-4255-0</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <section id="see_also">
    <h2>See also</h2>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absurdism">Absurdism</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_return">
        Eternal return</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theatre_of_the_Absurd">
        Theatre of the Absurd</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sickness_Unto_Death">
        The Sickness Unto Death</a> by <a lang="da" href=
        "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%B8ren_Kierkegaard">
        Søren Kierkegaard</a></li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <section id="external_links">
    <h2>External links</h2>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://dbanach.com/sisyphus.htm">Chapter 4 of the essay
        The Myth of Sisyphus</a>, by Albert Camus</li>
      <li><a href="http://www.sparknotes.com/philosophy/sisyphus/summary.html">
        SparkNotes on The Myth of Sisyphus</a></li>
      <li><a href="https://web.archive.org/web/20071012140207/http://www.geocities.com/a_and_e_uk/Sisyphus.htm">
        Suicide and Atheism: Camus and The Myth of Sisyphus</a> at the
        <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wayback_Machine">Wayback
        Machine</a> (archived October 12, 2007) by Richard Barnett</li>
      <li><a href="https://www.viu.ca/events/albert-camus-absurd-hero">
        The Absurd Hero</a> by Bob Lane</li>
    </ul>
  </section>

  <footer>
    <h4>Created by Name Surname<br>Source: <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Myth_of_Sisyphus">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Myth_of_Sisyphus</a></h4>
  </footer>

</main>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! 4. - I meant <aside> container with id="infobox", it's floated to the right and contains book cover image and basic info about it.

Comment: Ok, I made it responsive with media query.

Answer (score 0):

I used this jquery plugin to easily achieve #3 http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/ it's as simple as using the following: `$("#sidebar").stick_in_parent();` it will stop the element at the top after scrolling.  Has additional features for customizing to your needs.  This is not my plugin just one I have found success with.